# Implementing Login Form in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

I have created a simple login form in Powerapps using Canvas app.

Below shown is the code for Login Button

```
If(!IsBlank(
LookUp(AdminCredentialList, Title=username.Text And Password=passwrd.Text).Title,
Navigate(Screen2),
UpdateContext({ShowForgetMessage:true}))
```

In the above code I am getting an error

> powerapps unexpected characters. the formula contains 'eof' where 'parenclose' is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outermost function (If) is not closed. If you see this error message, there is also a tiny red underlining after your last character. Add another ')' at the end of your code and it should check out.

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula:

```
If(
    !IsBlank(LookUp(AdminCredentialList, Title = username.Text && Password = passwrd.Text).Title),
    Navigate(Screen2),
    UpdateContext({ShowForgetMessage: true})
)
```

**Documentation**: [LookUp function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup)